# How do I run a specific function based upon click.option chosen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, python-click

I am building a simple app which allows me to pass either a name or IP address which returns results in formatted output. This works fine except it produces two outputs or an error depending on which click.option I use:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--env', '-e', default='*', help='search for a specific environment')
@click.option('--ipaddr', '-i', required=False, help='search for a specific ip')
 
def main(env):
    
        ec2_info = get_instance_info(env)
        for i in ec2_info:
            if i in ec2_info:

                print("Id: {0}\tS: {1}\tName: {2}\tIP ADDR: {3}\tENVIRONMENT {4}\tINST TYPE: {5}".format(
                '%-20s' % i['InstanceID'],
                i['State'][0].upper(),
                '%-70s' % i['Name'],
                i['PrivateIpAddress'],
                '%-50s' % i['Environment'],
                i['InstanceType']
            ))

        ip_info = get_ip_info(ipaddr)

        for i in ip_info:
            if i in ip_info:
                print("Id: {0}\tS: {1}\tName: {2}\tIP ADDR: {3}\tENVIRONMENT {4}\tINST TYPE: {5}".format(
                '%-20s' % i['InstanceID'],
                i['State'][0].upper(),
                '%-70s' % i['Name'],
                i['PrivateIpAddress'],
                '%-50s' % i['Environment'],
                i['InstanceType']
            ))
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I pass the -e switch it shows the results and then errors on ipaddr because I haven't passed anything. If I choose -i it uses the default value and outputs both. How do only execute one of my functions at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the best way of handling this but I have simply added If statements to each of the sections under def main(env, ipaddr, role)